# How do I make an input method for my conlang

Tags: fonts, input-language, input-method

I am trying to make an input method for my constructed language, and have no idea where to start. I haven't found any helpful information on any forums. I am trying to make a syllabic language, so I would need it to work similarly to a Japanese input method. Type English letter combination like "tsu", get "つ".

Answer (score 0):

An easy way if using IBus for simple substitution input methods is to use ibus-table. So first:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-table
```

This includes a template file in `/usr/share/ibus-table/tables/template.txt` which you can copy and modify to fit your language. If you copied it to `my-lang.txt`, you can then build the database with:

```
ibus-table-createdb -s my-lang.txt -n my-lang.db
```

This will create the sqlite database. After that,

```
sudo cp my-lang.db /usr/share/ibus-table/tables/
```

After that either restart ibus by going to the indicator menu and selecting *Restart* (if ibus is not running you can start it with `ibus-daemon -d`). Then either running `ibus-setup` or selecting *Preferences* in the indicator, you can add your new input method on the *Input Method* tab (should be in *Other* in the dropdown menu), and select it in the indicator.

This is documented a bit here: https://code.google.com/p/ibus/wiki/HowToCreateATableForIBusTable

Also for a slightly better example than the default template, I suggest looking at the source for ibus-table-latex (assuming you have the source repositories enabled),

```
apt-get source ibus-table-latex
```

then check out `tables/latex.txt` in the downloaded ibus-table-other directory.